# How use "Var json = new" to create a known JSON ouput? (C#)

Tags: c#, formatting, format

Working on a project and basing it off a 2 year old project. Essentially here is what I'm trying to do:

Previously someone converted this:

```
{
    "referenceType": "PRO",
    "referenceNumber": "99959689585"
}
```

Into this:

```
var  json = new
        {
            referenceType = "PRO",
            referenceNumber = pro_number
        };
```

And I'm trying to do the same thing with something more complicated:

```
{
  "trackingInfo": [
    {
      "trackingNumberInfo": {
        "trackingNumber": "9084953743"
      }
    }
  ],
  "includeDetailedScans": false
}
```

I'm working in UIPATH. Trying to write an input to reach that output from above. How would I format a nested JSON

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the actual, formatted code here.

Comment: So next point, if we tell you the syntax, what are you going to do with that object? This is an odd question really, feel like an XP problem.

Comment: It's sort of working backwards - I'm working in UIPATH and trying to do an API call, which requires me to input the correct body. The third set of code is the exact body I need to input into the API call, but can't seem to format it correctly.

Comment: @user19953169: Do either of the answers that you got help you out?  The convention is to accept and/or upvote answers if they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just declaring this in steps, starting from children to the root which is the requested object.

```cs
object trackingNumberInfo = new {
    trackingNumber = "9084953743"
};

object obj = new {
    trackingNumberInfo = trackingNumberInfo
};

object[] trackingInfo =
{
    obj
};

object json = new
{
    trackingInfo = trackingInfo
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All in one line:

```
var myJson = new
{
    trackingInfo = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            trackingNumberInfo = new
            {
                trackingNumber = "9084953743"
            }
        }
    },
    includeDetailedScans = false
};
```

It creates an anonymous object that contains an array of anonymous objects and another property.

Converting it to JSON:

```
var asJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myJson);
```

Yields:

```json
{
  "trackingInfo": [
    {
      "trackingNumberInfo": {
        "trackingNumber": "9084953743"
      }
    }
  ],
  "includeDetailedScans": false
}
```